# Ajax Based DropDownList Event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a dropdownlist in my asp.net page.
I want to display database data on page based on dropdown value selected.

How can i do the same using ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the DropDownList inside an UpdatePanel and then subscribe to the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event after setting the [AutoPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx) property to `true`.

Here's an example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    protected void OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label.Text = string.Format("Selected value: {0}", ddl.SelectedValue);
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server" />

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList 
                    ID="ddl" 
                    runat="server" 
                    AutoPostBack="true" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnChange">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="item 1" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="item 2" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="item 3" />
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

To learn more about update panels and ASP.NET AJAX you may take a look at the [following article](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx).

Comment: I am new to asp.net. Can you provide some useful links so that it will be easier to implement same.

Comment: I have posted an example. Also here's a link you may take a look at: http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx